# 'Database Methods Cannot Be Reentrant' error even though there is no reentry Swift

Tags: swift, grdb

I am pretty new to swift and GRDB and am experiencing issues with this code. The exact error I get is 'Fatal error: Database methods are not reentrant.'. Due to the error, "Error occurred" is always printing. ConvertListToJSON doesn't interact with the DB. Any help would be appreciated

```
do {
    try dbQueue.write { db in
    try db.execute(
    sql: "INSERT INTO \(accountTableName) (\(accountUUID), \(accountEmailAddress), \(accountMainPhotoReference), \(accountPhotoTwoReference), \(accountPhotoThreeReference), \(accountPhotoFourReference), \(accountPhotoFiveReference), \(accountPhotoSixReference), \(accountBio), \(accountName), \(accountDOB), \(accountProfileComplete), \(accountInterests), \(accountLifestyle), \(accountGender), \(accountAgePrivacy), \(accountDistancePrivacy), \(accountPhoneNumber), \(accountShowReviewPopup)) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    arguments: [accountData[0], accountData[1], mainPhotoReference, photoTwoReference, photoThreeReference, photoFourReference, photoFiveReference, photoSixReference, accountData[8], accountData[9], accountData[10], accountData[11], convertListToJSON(list: Array(accountData[12..<16])), convertListToJSON(list: Array(accountData[17..<21])), accountData[22], accountData[23], accountData[24], accountData[25], "True"]
    )
   }
  }
catch {
  print("Error occurred")
}
```

I fixed previous errors with this code and tried debugging the code but I didn't gain enough information to solve the problem

Comment: "Fatal error: Database methods are not reentrant.", a fatal error implies the app crashed but maybe this is different in GRDB? Could you clarify if it crashes or if it throws an error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The app crashes when the error occurs

Comment: This is indeed a fatal error that crashes the app, because performing reentrant database accesses is not a runtime error that can be caught and handled: it is a programmer error that requires a change in the code. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, for people experiencing the same issue check how many places you use dbQueue.write and dbQueue.read. You can find the function and line that caused the error by looking through the numbered headings under Thread 1 on the left hand side of Xcode

Comment: Exactly . One must not nest database access methods such as `read` and `write`. This is a concurrency-safety measure, described in https://swiftpackageindex.com/groue/grdb.swift/documentation/grdb/concurrency#Synchronous-and-Asynchronous-Database-Accesses